# Vega: transform array of values into accepted format

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm using [Vega](https://github.com/vega/vega) for data visualization. Vega requires data which is shaped as an array of objects:

```
const accepted = [
    { num: 1, char: 'A' },
    { num: 2, char: 'B' },
    { num: 3, char: 'C' },
]
```

However, for sending data (e.g. via JSON), it is not efficient as the keys `num` and `char` are repeated multiple times. A more efficient way is sending the data as follows:

```
const efficient = {
   num: [1, 2, 3 ],
   char: ['A', 'B','C']
}
```

Right now I'm manually transforming the `efficient` structure above into the `accepted` structure before passing it into Vega. Is there any Vega transforms that I can use so taht I can pass `efficient` without having to transform it into `accepted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the flatten transform which should do what you need.

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/flatten/

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/flatten.html

Comment: Thanks David! I had a look at the `flatten` docs but didn't really understand them. I think the last entry ("Multi-field flattening") was the one that clicks.